# Release aplicacion Google Maps android nativo

Tags: android, google-maps

Estoy compilando una app que usa *google maps* en *android studio*. Su *debug* funciona perfecto, pero al compilar no carga el mapa. Quisiera saber qué error puedo estar teniendo. En ambos archivos localizados en `debug` y `release` llamado `google_maps_api` donde se define la llave la tengo definida. Entonces no sé que error pueda estar teniendo;

```
<string name="google_maps_key" templateMergeStrategy="preserve" translatable="true">MICLAVE</string>
```

Mi *manifest*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
 package="com.ponny.radiomobile" >

<!--
     The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
     Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
     location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality. 
-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <!--
         The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
         (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
         Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
         You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
         sign the APK for publishing.
         You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/. 
    -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.ponny.radiomobile.MapsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_maps"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
</application>
```

Comment: Agregaste el sha de debug en la consola de google?

Comment: Si señor , el certificado

Comment: Que ves? Hay errores en logcat?

Comment: A mi me sucedía igual, lo que hice fue **recrear la clave en la consola** y agregarla de nuevo al proyecto.

Comment: Su debug funciona perfecto pero al compilar no carga el mapa? Se supone que si realizas un debug la aplicación se compila.

Comment: El debug muestra bien carga el mapa pero al generar el APK , ya no funciona

Comment: el APK firmado??? entonces te falta un SHA :)

Comment: como asi me falta uno , ya tengo mi sha e hice el debug

Comment: Muchachos, no generen el apk, solo pongan "Build apk" y prueben

Comment: Perdón tengo el mismo error ya he buscado en varios lados, lo lograste resolver. gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ten en cuenta que cuando liberas la aplicación o la compilas en modo release necesitas otro API key para la API de Google Maps, ya que una unicamente funcionara en modo desarrollador o debug, cuando ya se va a liberar es necesario generar su API key para el release utilizando los siguientes comandos.

```
keytool -list -keystore your_keystore_name

keytool -list -v -keystore your_keystore_name -alias your_alias_name
```

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/signup?hl=es

Comment: Es decir debo utilizar un api key diferente para debug y otro diferente para release aunque la clave generada la genere con el comando que me muestras?

Comment: Asi es, en el link que incluyo como fuente indica que hay que generar el certificado de depuración o debug y posteriormente al liberar el certificado de liberación, esto porque se genera un keystore exclusivo para tu aplicación y es con la que se publicará en la play store.

Comment: Okey muchas gracias , voy a probar